# How can i Precompile my JSP using ANT?

Tags: jsp, ant, compilation, build.xml

How can I pre-compile my jsp using jspc (jasper) in ANT , I Do not have any server installed in my system ..

Need assistance .

Thanks in advance .

Comment: What's preventing u from doing it? have you looked at ANT's [document](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jspc.html)?

Comment: Yeah . Document helped , Using jspc tag I am able to do it now. Thanks @Sas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jspc tag I am able to do it now.